# Where is the MAT-File library source code?

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I see everyone talking about the mathworks provided MAT-File library and api, but I can't seem to find a download link anywhere.... I admit this isn't coding related but it seemed the most appropriate place to ask.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/ or http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html (looks like a product you need to purchase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matroot\extern\include\mat.h, its in there, "matroot" is your matlab installation directory